# Error in driver during machine creation - docker

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I'm newbie with Docker, I try to create docker machine on my windows 10 (Home ver unfort.).
1st command I use "docker-machine create -d virtualbox anewmachine" which gave me following error:

```
  "This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory",
```

Then I found solution for the above error on stack, that is "docker-machine create default --virtualbox-no-vtx-check". This one seems working but ended up to the following error:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(default) Copying C:\Users\The Kash\.docker\machine\cache\boot2docker.iso to C:\Users\The 
Kash\.docker\machine\machines\default\boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Windows might ask for the permission to configure a dhcp server. Sometimes, such 
 confirmation window is minimized in the taskbar.
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Unable to start the VM: 
B:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe startvm default --type headless failed:
VBoxManage.exe: error: Call to VidMessageSlotMap failed: Last=0xc000000d/87 
(VERR_NEM_VM_CREATE_FAILED)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface 
IConsole
```

Please help me.

Comment: Docker Desktop works on Windows Home... https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-desktop-for-windows-home-is-here/

Comment: As stated in the first error message, VT-X/AMD-v is mandatory to create a virtualbox VM. The option you found just avoid to check for this but doesn't make it work. You need to enable VT-X/AMD-v in the BIOS (as explained in the first error message)